# Update progress-bar status every time page is loaded

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, progress

Im using [Minddust amazing progress bar](http://www.minddust.com/project/bootstrap-progressbar/) with the following code:

Basically Im using php timestamp to set the range between two specific dates/times and using progress bar to display the status.

```
<div id="prg" class="progress">  
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" data transitiongoal="1418779020" aria-valuemin="1418778256" aria-valuemax="1418779020"></div> 
</div>
```

data transitiongoal, aria-valuemin and aria-valuemax are dinamicaly loaded from a database each time the page is loaded.

JQuery

```
<script>
    $('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar(
        {
        display_text: 'fill',
        refresh_rate: 300,

        update: function(current_percentage) { $('#update').html(current_percentage); }
        });

</script>
```

Unfortunely, every time page refreshes or loads up the progress bar goes back to the start to 0%, altough it runs faster than before because the initial startdate/time has changed.

What Im trying to do is to set the appropriate percentage, and fill up the progress bar to the accurate percentage/value each time the page is loaded/refresh.

Since this progress bar has no width property to set up, and no intial value to define, how can I get  the appropriate value every time page is loaded instead of running back from the beggining?

Many thanks for your suggestions